# Retrieving data from ajax request

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

I try to webscrap data of all past ufc matches from this page https://www.ufc.com/events#events-list-past.

And it has ajax request "load more" so when trying to send request to ajax it returns 404

```
headers = {'Accept': 'text/html',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0'}
url = 'https://www.ufc.com/views/ajax?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(page.status_code)
```

How can I load all these matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to send the payload along the request:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = 'https://www.ufc.com/views/ajax?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax'

payload = {
    "view_name": "events_upcoming_past_solr",
    "view_display_id": "past",
    "view_args": "",
    "view_path": "/events",
    "view_base_path": "",
    "view_dom_id": "8177974293330a03393b98761bd5673fd3b427b60e6d7c5b5b54a6ca34144791",
    "pager_element": "0",
    "page": 1,
    "_drupal_ajax": "1",
    "ajax_page_state[theme]": "ufc",
    "ajax_page_state[theme_token]": "",
    "ajax_page_state[libraries]": "addtoany/addtoany,classy/base,classy/messages,core/normalize,core/picturefill,dve/video,field_group/element.horizontal_tabs,google_analytics/google_analytics,layout_discovery/onecol,poll/drupal.poll-links,system/base,ufc/buttons,ufc/card-content-footer,ufc/card-event,ufc/carousel,ufc/filter-select,ufc/global-css,ufc/global-js,ufc/greensock-tweenmax,ufc/hero,ufc/how-to-watch-event,ufc/how-to-watch-event-group,ufc/in-action,ufc/links-dropdown,ufc/menu-main,ufc/page,ufc/sidebar-first,ufc/site-footer,ufc/site-header,ufc/tabs,ufc_events/eventsList,ufc_localization/region,ufc_localization/timezoner,ufc_yext/search_bar,views/views.ajax,views/views.module,views_infinite_scroll/views-infinite-scroll"
}

for payload['page'] in range(0, 4):  # <-- increase page numbers here
    data = requests.post(api_url, data=payload).json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data[-1]['data'], 'html.parser')
    # print some data from the response:
    for title in soup.select('h3'):
        print(title.text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
Pavlovich vs Blaydes
Holloway vs Allen
Pereira vs Adesanya 2
Vera vs Sandhagen
Edwards vs Usman 3
Yan vs Dvalishvili
Jones vs Gane
Muniz vs Allen
Andrade vs Blanchfield
Makhachev vs Volkanovski
Lewis vs Spivac
Teixeira vs Hill
Strickland vs Imavov
Cannonier vs Strickland
Blachowicz vs Ankalaev
Thompson vs Holland
Nzechukwu vs Cutelaba
Adesanya vs Pereira
Rodriguez vs Lemos
Kattar vs Allen
Oliveira vs Makhachev
Grasso vs Araujo
Dern vs Yan

...
```